# SQL IN-based Loop in function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, for-loop

I want to write an SQL function which goes through list of records (only integers ids)returned from an SQL query and execute another function using those parameters:

- I don't want to enumerate all ids by hand, i.e. I want to have them first returned by an SQL query, so SET @recordlist = (SELECT ..),
- I want to have a loop which executes another function for each element of the record list, i.e. I want to be able to access each single element from the record list in a FOR statement

It should look like:

```
SET @recordlist = (SELECT ..)

For every element e in the recordlist

Execute function f(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to make it work. Just copy & paste, change the query and the name of the function.

```
   DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `my`$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `my`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT `myval` FROM my_table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN curs1;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH curs1 INTO i;
    IF done THEN
    LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SELECT myfunc(i);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE curs1;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a routine with a loop cursor to achieve this !

```
   delimiter//
    create procedure get_balance()
    begin
    DECLARE var1;
    DECLARE flag INT DEFAULT 0;
    .......
       declare tcursor for select col1,col2.... from table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET flag = 1;
    open tcursor;
    myloop:LOOP
    fetch tcursor into col1,col2...;
    if flag = 1 then
    -- function here 
    call funtion;
    leave myloop;
    end if
    end loop myloop;
    close tcursor;
    end//
    delimiter;
```

Comment: Up_One for me ! kkk Thx